# What is difference between ISUP call and ISDN call?

Tags: gsm, ss7

Can anyone tell me the actual difference between ISUP and ISDN call and how do we decide which one to use?
Question is very basic but i always find difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISDN is a set of standards for voice, video and data communications over traditional circuit switched networks.

It includes standards for the protocols between the end devices (e.g. phone) and the switch in the public network and standards for the signalling between one switch and another in the public network.

ISUP is part of the suite and is a protocol that is used between switches in the public network - often called trunk calls, or more accurately trunk legs of an end to end call.

So strictly speaking an ISDN call is any call which includes ISDN end points and signalling and an ISUP call is a specific connection between two points (usually public switches) which uses the ISUP signalling system.

As the internet emerged and evolved, some of this technology also made its way into the VoIP world with some VoIP signalling growing out of ISUP signalling for example - specifically BICC (Bearer Independent Call Control).

I suspect that knowing this you may now have a different question, so fire away...

**Update**

ISDN standards include two access protocols, BRI and PRI.

BRI is Basic Rate access and is targeted at residential and small business and provides two voice channels and one data channel.

PRI is Primary rate access and is targeted at business with PABX's (their own internal switchboards). It provides either 23 voice channels and one data channel in North America, or 30 voice channels and one data channel in Europe.

This was all designed in the days before the internet and ADSL so it was seen at the time as way to provide higher speed data to subscribers while still allowing them make calls. Dial up modems took over the whole subscriber line so calls could not be made.

ISDN BRI was never particularly popular and when the internet arrived it became even less so.

ISDN PRI was used quite heavily for connecting PABX's to the public network.

For your situation, it sounds like you have a modern public network which is using Call Servers and Media Gateways. The Media Gateways terminate the subscriber lines and convert from the TDM access world, into the public backbone network (which is mostly likely IP, MPLS or ATM in your case). The Media gateways also terminate trunk calls from traditional TDM switches in older public networks.

Calls you are seeing with an ISDN setup message are likely from PABX connections, although they could be from BRI lines.

Calls with ISUP IAM messages are most likely from older TDM switches connecting into the newer Call Server and Media Gateway network - i.e. Trunk calls.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Mick the basic doubt is still not clear Actually i have a device called Media gateway which receives request from PSTN network. What i am seeing here is from some network it is receiving ISUP request (IAM) and some network it is receiving ISDN(SETUP). To simulated the issue we use SCTP connection to SGX for ISUP call and will connect cable to SGX for ISDN call.
Is it like landline calls which has wire connectivity uses ISDN and GSX calls (mobile) use ISUP. Sorry if my understanding wrong but i am very much eager to know the difference in practical way.

Comment: @SHAHIDNX - Answer updated - hopefully this covers your questions.

Comment: Understanding little bit  but still in confusion at very basic level. Some information i got from google is as below. 1. Wiki said ISDN is part of link layer of IP protocol suit where as ISUP is part of application layer of ss7 2. From some other link ISDN is used for call process and ss7(ISUP) for signalling.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is about two different protocols: SS7/ISUP (IAM) and DSS1 (SETUP message).
To keep it simple, ISUP is an international signalling protocol to route calls between swichting exchanges, networks, countries. You don't know topology behind an ISUP swiching exchange, so any kind of call can arrive from there.
DSS1 is the signalling protocol to communicate to the nearest switching exchange, then the task is taken over by ISUP unless the call destination is a subscriber within the same switching exchange. Behind a DSS1 line nothing but a bunch of landline subscribers are to be expected (dead end).